# Getting Warning When Uploading any apk

Tags: android, apk

I get this warning, every time myapp's apk file upload on Google Play Store.

> You uploaded an APK that uses Google Play services version 50890000. This will only work with Android API levels of 9 and above. It is discouraged to use this Google Play services version unless you have set the minSdkVersion in your manifest to 9 or higher

what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means that u use the Google Play service Version 50890000 - Google Play service requires Androids API Version 9 (or higher). It seems like you have a lower version specified in your manifest file. But to reflect the requirements of GPs it's recommented to set it also to set your Apps min required API version to 9.

For mor specific information about the minSdkVersion attribute take a look on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min